# how to upload a file from android application to google drive

Tags: android

i want to upload a text file or any file from any android application to google drive.i am using this below code.but its not working proporly.can any one please help me.how to solve this.

this is main activity

```
package com.intel.driveapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    static final int                REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
    static final int                REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 2;
    static final int                RESULT_STORE_FILE = 4;
    private static Uri              mFileUri;
    private  Drive          mService;
    private GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    private Context                 mContext;
    private List<File>              mResultList;
    private ListView                mListView;
    private String[]                mFileArray;
    private String                  mDLVal;
    private ArrayAdapter            mAdapter;
    private final HttpTransport m_transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    private final JsonFactory m_jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Connect to Google Drive
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));

        mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                m_transport, m_jsonFactory, mCredential).setApplicationName("AppName/1.0")
                .build();

        startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                downloadItemFromList(position);
            }
        };

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler); 

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_STORE_FILE);
            }
        });

        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                getDriveContents();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getDriveContents()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                mResultList = new ArrayList<File>();
                com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files f1 = mService.files();
                com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List request = null;

                do 
                {
                    try 
                    { 
                        request = f1.list();
                        request.setQ("trashed=false");
                        com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList fileList = request.execute();

                        mResultList.addAll(fileList.getItems());
                        request.setPageToken(fileList.getNextPageToken());
                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                        startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if (request != null)
                        {
                            request.setPageToken(null);
                        }
                    }
                } while (request.getPageToken() !=null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

                populateListView();
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    private void downloadItemFromList(int position)
    {
        mDLVal = (String) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        showToast("You just pressed: " + mDLVal);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                for(File tmp : mResultList)
                {
                    if (tmp.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(mDLVal))
                    {
                        if (tmp.getDownloadUrl() != null && tmp.getDownloadUrl().length() >0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse resp = 
                                        mService.getRequestFactory()
                                        .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(tmp.getDownloadUrl()))
                                        .execute();
                                InputStream iStream = resp.getContent();
                                try 
                                {
                                    final java.io.File file = new java.io.File(Environment
                                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath(), 
                                            tmp.getTitle());
                                    showToast("Downloading: " + tmp.getTitle() + " to " + Environment
                                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath());
                                    storeFile(file, iStream);
                                } finally {
                                    iStream.close();
                                }

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    private void populateListView()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                mFileArray = new String[mResultList.size()];
                int i = 0;
                for(File tmp : mResultList)
                {
                    mFileArray[i] = tmp.getTitle();
                    i++;
                }
                mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mFileArray);
                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    private void storeFile(java.io.File file, InputStream iStream)
    {
        try 
        {
            final OutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while ((read = iStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        oStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    oStream.flush();
                } finally {
                    oStream.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) 
    {
        switch (requestCode) 
        {
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) 
                {
                    String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        mService = getDriveService(mCredential);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    //account already picked
                } else {
                    startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
                }
                break;
            case RESULT_STORE_FILE:
                mFileUri = data.getData();
                // Save the file to Google Drive
                saveFileToDrive();
                break;
        }
    }

    private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
            .build();
      }


    private void saveFileToDrive() 
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    /*Context context;
                    String currentDBPath = "//data//" + context.getPackageName()
                            + "//databases//" + databaseName + "";*/


                    // Create URI from real path
                    String path;
                    path = getPathFromUri(mFileUri);
                    mFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(path));

                    ContentResolver cR = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver();

                    // File's binary content
                    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(mFileUri.getPath());
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(cR.getType(mFileUri), fileContent);

                    showToast("Selected " + mFileUri.getPath() + "to upload");

                    // File's meta data. 
                    File body = new File();
                    body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                    body.setMimeType("text/plain");

                    com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files f1 = mService.files();
                    com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Insert i1 = f1.insert(body, mediaContent);
                    File file = i1.execute();

                    if (file != null) 
                    {
                        showToast("Uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                    }
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showToast("Transfer ERROR: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public void showToast(final String toast) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public String getPathFromUri(Uri uri) 
    {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

}
```

but when i am uploading a image ,its showing which image is selected but after that one toast message is showing 
**tranfer error: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extentions.amdroid.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException**

Comment: Have you got the required Android API key for the app (obtained using the keytool/keystore) included in the Google developers console?

Comment: thanks for your reply Mark Keen.
no i didn't get the android api key.can u please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Have a read of this link, It should guide you through the necessary steps in order to get a API key:  https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a db file to google drive from android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491984/how-to-upload-a-db-file-to-google-drive-from-android-application)