# How to upload a db file to google drive from android application?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to upload a db file from my app to google drive. I am able to create a folder in google drive but I am not getting how to upload db file .

This is my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Metadata;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;

import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
//import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

//import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;


public class MainActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    DriveId folderId;
    private static Uri  fileUri;


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);


        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setTitle("New folder").build();
        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
        .createFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet)
        .setResultCallback(folderCreatedCallback);
        saveToDrive();
    }

    ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult> folderCreatedCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveFolderResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
                return;
            }


            folderId = result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId();
            showMessage("Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId());
        }
    };


    final ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallBack = new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult driveFileResult) {

            if (!driveFileResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Error while trying to create the file");
                return;
            }
            //Initialize mFile to be processed in AsyncTask
            DriveFile mfile = driveFileResult.getDriveFile();
            new EditContentsAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute(mfile);

        }
    };

         public void saveToDrive()
         {
               fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath()
                        + "/data/com.example.dbupload/databases/Student"));

                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());

                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(getMimeType("db"), fileContent);
                File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();

                        body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                        body.setMimeType(getMimeType("db"));

             //   File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();


         }


    public class EditContentsAsyncTask extends ApiClientAsyncTask<DriveFile, Void, Boolean> {

        public EditContentsAsyncTask(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackgroundConnected(DriveFile... args) {
            DriveFile file = args[0];
            try {

                DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = file.open(
                        getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).await();


                if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    return false;
                }

                DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();



                //edit the outputStream
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
                String inFileName = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(db.getDatabaseName()).getPath();
                //DATABASE PATH

                FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(driveContents.getOutputStream());
                int n = 0;
                while ((n = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
                in.close();


                com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status =
                        driveContents.commit(getGoogleApiClient(), null).await();
                return status.getStatus().isSuccess();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException while appending to the output stream", e);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (!result) {
                showMessage("Error while editing contents");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("Successfully edited contents");
        }
    }

    private String getMimeType(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am able to create a folder in drive. can any one please help me what I should do for uploading a db file?

Comment: Thank you  Arjun. Can you please help me for the above issue?

Answer (score 6):

First, the fact that I'm seeing these imports:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
...
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
```

indicates that you're mixing [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) and the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) Api. Do not do it unless you want to get in [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2037269%20mixing).

So, when you got your FolderId, it is a parent of your 'DB' file, I presume (and if the DB file is a SQLite type, your MIME TYPE should be 'application/x-sqlite3').

Anyway, in GDAA, you first have to turn your java.io.File (that represents the 'DB') into ***content***. And you have to supply ***metadata*** (like file title, mime type, flags ...). You got the metadata right, it is the content you tripped over. The following snippet should do what you need (don't hold me accountable, I slammed it together in 5 minutes - no testing)

```
/******************************************************************
   * create file in GOODrive
   * @param pFldr parent's ID
   * @param titl  file name
   * @param mime  file mime type  (application/x-sqlite3)
   * @param file  file (with content) to create
   */
  static void saveToDrive(final DriveFolder pFldr, final String titl, 
                                      final String mime, final java.io.File file) {
    if (getGoogleApiClient() != null && pFldr != null && titl != null && mime != null && file != null) try {
      // create content from file
      Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult) {
          DriveContents cont = driveContentsResult != null && driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess() ?
            driveContentsResult.getDriveContents() : null;

          // write file to content, chunk by chunk   
          if (cont != null) try {
            OutputStream oos = cont.getOutputStream();
            if (oos != null) try {
              InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
              byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
              int c;
              while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                oos.write(buf, 0, c);
                oos.flush();
              }
            }
            finally { oos.close();}

            // content's COOL, create metadata
            MetadataChangeSet meta = new Builder().setTitle(titl).setMimeType(mime).build();

            // now create file on GooDrive
            pFldr.createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), meta, cont).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onResult(DriveFileResult driveFileResult) {
                if (driveFileResult != null && driveFileResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                  // BINGO
                } else {
                  // report error
                }
              }
            });
          } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
```

I noticed, you're adapting the 'official' [GDAA DEMO](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) for your project. In case it is not sufficient or overwhelming, you may also look at this [demo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo), that takes a different approach to the same problem.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Check your mime type of database file.

```
private String getMimeType(String string) {
    //set return "application/x-sqlite3";
    return "application/x-sqlite3";
}
```