# I only want to upload files to Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

There is a way to create and upload files to the official Google Docs and demo sources.

But there is no way to upload existing files.

I want to know how to upload a file (ex. Sqlite db file) of an Android app to Google Drive.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the [Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) on how to manage file content and metadata. You can create files in two ways with the Drive Android API: using the [`DriveClient.newCreateFileActivityIntentSender`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveClient.html#newCreateFileActivityIntentSender(com.google.android.gms.drive.CreateFileActivityOptions)) method and the [`CreateFileActivityOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/CreateFileActivityOptions.html) class; or using the [`DriveResourceClient.createFile`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveResourceClient.html#createFile(com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder,com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet,com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents)) method.

You may also check these links for additional reference:

- [How to upload a db file to google drive from android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491984/how-to-upload-a-db-file-to-google-drive-from-android-application)
- [Android Open and Save files to/from Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk)
- [How to upload a file to Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675689/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive)

Comment: Note that as of December 2018, the Google Drive Android API is in the process of being deprecated by Google.

Answer (score -1):

```
private fun handleSignInIntent(resultIntent: Intent) {
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(resultIntent)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign-in Successful!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val credentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                this,
                Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)
            )
            credentials.selectedAccount = it.account
            val drive =
                Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), GsonFactory(), credentials)
                    .setApplicationName("DB BackUp").build()

            driveServiceHelper=DriveServiceHelper(drive)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign-in Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

// Drive Service Helper class : 
class DriveServiceHelper(private val driveService: Drive) {
    private val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    fun createFile(filePath: String): Task<String> {
        return Tasks.call(executor,object : Callable<String>{
            override fun call(): String {
                val fileMetadata=File()
                fileMetadata.name="BACKUP_SAMPLE"

                val fileToUpload = java.io.File(filePath)

                val mediaContent = FileContent("*/*", fileToUpload)

                var myFile = File()
                try {
                    myFile=driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).execute()
                } catch (e:Exception){
                    Log.e("DriveException>>", "${e.message} <<<")
                }

                if (myFile==null)
                    throw IOException("Null file received on Creation")

                return myFile.id
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting just a link, post an explanation here. So, even if the link becomes available in the future, people could still refer to your answer.

Comment: please remove your downvote I've added the code